# System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection not available under a class library

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, configurationsection

I'm migrating a piece of functionality from my App_Code directory to a separate project that's going to build a class library to be referenced by my web app.  One of my classes in the App_Code piece inherits form System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection, like so:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Namespace P10.WebStore

#Region "WebStore Section"
    Public Class WebStoreSection
        Inherits ConfigurationSection
```

I absolutely cannot get the project to recognize ConfigurationSection as a class. Nothing I google about this class mentions having to do anything special to use it.  Is it because this is a class library and not an .exe or somethign?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type [`ConfigurationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) is found in the assembly `System.Configuration`. Did you add a reference to that assembly in your class library project?

Comment: Geez, that was it.  Thanks.  I added probably a dozen references to try and mirror the project it's coming from, but that wasn't one of them.  I don't know why I didn't think to check that one.  Oh, wait, yes I do: I'm a moron.  

Thanks!

Comment: @fr0man I just had the exact same issue and fixed it by finding this question so your 'stupidity' helped me out! I wouldn't have thought such a common piece of functionality needed manually adding an assembly reference.